# Play framework cannot handle list index greater than 255. How to handle it?

Tags: java, indexing, playframework-2.1

I am facing issue while binding my form with an `ArrayList` of objects which contains maximum 500 elements but I found out that Play does not support indices greater than 255.
I found a solution in some post which recommends to use `Hashmap` instead of `List`. But for me now its very complicated to change my entire data structure from `List` to `HashMap`.

Can anybody suggest me the solution?

Comment: Show us some code sample or at least give us a link(s) to _some post_

Comment: Taking example of sample form application of Play Framework  where I have Contact form which contains List of object of Profile class.So I want maximum number of Profiles should be 500 but its Play Spring Binder doesn't allow index greater than 256.So what should be done to solve this problem.